How can I get this mesh to stop distorting on import?
I have a robot character with armature and animation, and it displays correctly in Noesis:

The armature is shown in red, and I've selected a specific bone named Dummy010, shown in red/blue/yellow at the bottom left of the image.  Everything seems to be working just fine until I import the character into Blender:

The same bone, Dummy010, is highlighted at the left edge of that image, but as you can see, the same thing is happening to all four legs.  I'm using an add-on called Better FBX Importer/Exporter, but the same thing happens with the regular FBX importer.
Here's my .blend file:
robot .blend file
How can I get this distortion to stop happening?

Check if the bones are at their zero pose position in both cases.

Could you check where is the origin of the armature compared to the origin of the mesh BEFORE export ? It seems that the mesh is shifted in Blender, the main bone not being right under the legs platform, as in Neosis.

It's easy to fix:

Select the armature and switch to Pose Mode
Press A to select all bones
Pose > Clear Transform > All


Please stop rolling back changes when we are applying the proper formatting on this site.
